# How to make a variable or attribute be referred to by a different local name within javascript?

Tags: javascript, variables, reference

For example, I have this simple for loop that iterates through a list and is finding the attribute called amount.

```
lst.forEach(function (d) {
if(d.amount){} else {d.amount = 0};
});
```

I don't want to actually redefine the actual data or add another piece of data. I just want to call it 'x', but actually have it refer to 'amount'. In other words, I'd like to refer to 'amount' by a different localname.

For example,

```
x = amount #I'm telling the computer "Hey comp, when I type x, I actually mean amount"
lst.forEach(function (d) {
if(d.x){} else {d.x = 0};
});
```

As a result this would produce the same amount.

Is this possible?

Comment: @dystroy yes you can use bracket notation for object properties, good call. However i think OP was suggesting more, eg `var x = 'myfunc';
var myfunc = function(){...}
x();` which will not work, unlike variable variables in php `$x = 'myfunc';
$myfunc = function(){...}
$$x();` which would

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript is a dynamic language where you can refer to properties by name. What you want is to use the [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) to access your property :

var

```
var x = "amount"
lst.forEach(function (d) {
   if(d[x]){} else {d[x] = 0};
});
```